# no Data are restore from backup

Tags: python, django, django-models, backup, restore

I have used django-dbbackup to get back up from database, There is a profile for each member, which is connected to "User" as "OneToOneField", The problem is that while restoring, no data restoring in the profile table, The other tables are restoring properly.
these warnings printed in CMD

```
D:\CODES\python\virtualenvs\karapp2\.env\Lib\site-packages\dbbackup\db\sqlite.py:78: UserWarning: Error in db restore: index auth_group_permissions_group_id_permission_id_0cd325b0_uniq already exists
  warnings.warn(f"Error in db restore: {err}")
D:\CODES\python\virtualenvs\karapp2\.env\Lib\site-packages\dbbackup\db\sqlite.py:78: UserWarning: Error in db restore: index auth_user_groups_user_id_group_id_94350c0c_uniq already exists
  warnings.warn(f"Error in db restore: {err}")
D:\CODES\python\virtualenvs\karapp2\.env\Lib\site-packages\dbbackup\db\sqlite.py:78: UserWarning: Error in db restore: index auth_user_user_permissions_user_id_permission_id_14a6b632_uniq already exists
  warnings.warn(f"Error in db restore: {err}")
D:\CODES\python\virtualenvs\karapp2\.env\Lib\site-packages\dbbackup\db\sqlite.py:78: UserWarning: Error in db restore: index django_content_type_app_label_model_76bd3d3b_uniq already exists
  warnings.warn(f"Error in db restore: {err}")
D:\CODES\python\virtualenvs\karapp2\.env\Lib\site-packages\dbbackup\db\sqlite.py:78: UserWarning: Error in db restore: index taggit_taggeditem_content_type_id_object_id_tag_id_4bb97a8e_uniq already exists
  warnings.warn(f"Error in db restore: {err}")
D:\CODES\python\virtualenvs\karapp2\.env\Lib\site-packages\dbbackup\db\sqlite.py:78: UserWarning: Error in db restore: index app_base_share_Workgroup_share_id_department_id_c474420a_uniq already exists
  warnings.warn(f"Error in db restore: {err}")
D:\CODES\python\virtualenvs\karapp2\.env\Lib\site-packages\dbbackup\db\sqlite.py:78: UserWarning: Error in db restore: index app_base_meet_TargetUser_meet_id_user_id_ae3dccd4_uniq already exists
  warnings.warn(f"Error in db restore: {err}")
D:\CODES\python\virtualenvs\karapp2\.env\Lib\site-packages\dbbackup\db\sqlite.py:78: UserWarning: Error in db restore: index app_base_meet_Workgroup_meet_id_department_id_9092086a_uniq already exists
  warnings.warn(f"Error in db restore: {err}")
D:\CODES\python\virtualenvs\karapp2\.env\Lib\site-packages\dbbackup\db\sqlite.py:78: UserWarning: Error in db restore: index auth_permission_content_type_id_codename_01ab375a_uniq already exists
  warnings.warn(f"Error in db restore: {err}")
D:\CODES\python\virtualenvs\karapp2\.env\Lib\site-packages\dbbackup\db\sqlite.py:78: UserWarning: Error in db restore: FOREIGN KEY constraint failed
  warnings.warn(f"Error in db restore: {err}")
D:\CODES\python\virtualenvs\karapp2\.env\Lib\site-packages\dbbackup\db\sqlite.py:78: UserWarning: Error in db restore: unrecognized token: "'if(!file){
"
  warnings.warn(f"Error in db restore: {err}")
D:\CODES\python\virtualenvs\karapp2\.env\Lib\site-packages\dbbackup\db\sqlite.py:78: UserWarning: Error in db restore: near "toastifier": syntax error
  warnings.warn(f"Error in db restore: {err}")
D:\CODES\python\virtualenvs\karapp2\.env\Lib\site-packages\dbbackup\db\sqlite.py:78: UserWarning: Error in db restore: near "return": syntax error
  warnings.warn(f"Error in db restore: {err}")
D:\CODES\python\virtualenvs\karapp2\.env\Lib\site-packages\dbbackup\db\sqlite.py:78: UserWarning: Error in db restore: unrecognized token: "}"
  warnings.warn(f"Error in db restore: {err}")
D:\CODES\python\virtualenvs\karapp2\.env\Lib\site-packages\dbbackup\db\sqlite.py:78: UserWarning: Error in db restore: UNIQUE constraint failed: auth_permission.id
  warnings.warn(f"Error in db restore: {err}")
D:\CODES\python\virtualenvs\karapp2\.env\Lib\site-packages\dbbackup\db\sqlite.py:78: UserWarning: Error in db restore: UNIQUE constraint failed: django_content_type.id
  warnings.warn(f"Error in db restore: {err}")
D:\CODES\python\virtualenvs\karapp2\.env\Lib\site-packages\dbbackup\db\sqlite.py:78: UserWarning: Error in db restore: UNIQUE constraint failed: django_migrations.id
  warnings.warn(f"Error in db restore: {err}")
```